# Abort an ext js grid store ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs3

I need to abort a [EXT JS store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) load (which is a grid panel store using an ajax call).

I am using Ext JS 3.4

I have tried the following.

```
Ext.Ajax.abort(store.proxy.activeRequest);
delete store.proxy.activeRequest;
```

Comment: And what is the result of above code? any error or warning?

Comment: I am getting an error like "Error: TypeError: this.activeRequest is undefined"

Comment: What kind of store proxy you are using? 
Kindly post your code for store and ajax request and it would be great if you could make a https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home for it.

Comment: Indeed inside the latest documentation I cannot find the activeRequest parameter: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by giving a condition,

```
var activeRequest = store.proxy.activeRequest;

if (typeof activeRequest.read != 'undefined') 
{ 
    Ext.Ajax.abort(activeRequest.read); 
}
```